# Display dataframe column headers as a Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have some data frame with 1050 columns, how to display column name in single column view.

```
list(df) # will give all column name in list, but i need to see in column
['FIPST', 'SECTOR', 'N07_EMPLOYER', 'RG', 'TABWGT', 'EMPLOYMENT_NOISY', 'PAYROLL_NOISY', 'RECEIPTS_NOISY', 'PCT1', 'PCT2', 'PCT3', 'PCT4', 'ETH1', ....]
```

Expected:

```
ColumnName
FIPST
SECTOR
N07_EMPLOYER
RG
TABWGT
EMPLOYMENT_NOISY
```

Tried:

```
df.columns.to_series()
```

but it showing in 2 column & won't show entire column list, in middle ...
[image]

Comment: Does `df.columns.to_series()` work?

Comment: If you only need this to "see", just loop over and use print `for c in df: print c`?

Comment: @Psidom, yes like this only, but in single column, it shows in 2 column & I need complete list.

Comment: @Zero, yes working...

Comment: `df.columns.to_series().reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, thanks, but in middle it show ... if data frame has more columns, I use for c in df: print(c)

Comment: @faithon.gvr.py It wasn't very clear what exactly you wanted to do with the columns (besides printing them out), so I've written an answer that would address all possible concerns you might have.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, thanks, I accepted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
To get a series/dataframe from column headers. You'd consider this option if you want to do more than just *printing* out those headers.

1. First, change your display options, so more rows are displayed. You can do this be changing the `max_rows` attribute in `pd.options`:

   ```
   pd.options.display.max_rows = len(df.columns)
   ```
2. Next, as [Psidom suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377155/display-data-frame-column-name-in-column-python-3-6?noredirect=1#comment79712998_46377155), use `df.columns.to_series`:

   ```
   print(df.columns.to_series().reset_index(drop=True))
   ```

---

**Option 2**
Just printing the column headers out. You can do this in one of two ways. One is as [Jon Clements suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377155/display-data-frame-column-name-in-column-python-3-6/46377308?noredirect=1#comment79713296_46377308):

```
print(*df.columns, sep='\n')
```

Alternatively, you could loop over `df.columns` as as [Zero suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377155/display-data-frame-column-name-in-column-python-3-6/46377308?noredirect=1#comment79713040_46377155):

```
for c in df.columns: print(c)
```

Comment: @JonClements Definitely yes, but it seems like OP wants a pandas object out of these column headers.

Comment: Umm... that doesn't make much sense - as when you've printed it there isn't an object except the object you've already got access to via `df.columns`

Comment: @JonClements Sorry, I meant as a series or dataframe.

Comment: Yes... but you've already got it as that via `df.columns` getting it printed 1 column name per line doesn't change anything

Comment: @JonClements, Jon `df.columns` returns a list. From what their "expected output" gave me to believe, it seems that they wanted a series they could do something more with than just printing out. I definitely might've read too much into it, so I edited my answer, and CW'd it.

Comment: You could well be right... I was just going by *how to display column name in single column view*....